# Self signed certificate VS CA certificate for REST APIs over https

Tags: rest, ssl, mobile, https, certificate

Let's say we have a server only running REST API services, only on HTTPS.
The only consumer of the APIs is a mobile app.
Do we need certificate from CA or a self signed certificate is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can :

- Keep a self-signed certificate, but then you have to pin the certificate, and you can't revoke it if the private key is compromised.
- Use a home made certificate authorities, but then you have to pin the certificate, and manage the revocation process (maintain an OCSP or CRL).
- Use a certificate from a trusted CA, revocation will be checked for you, and if you want additional security, you still can pin the certificate.

In my opinion, the use of a trusted CA is more secure and more simple.

Comment: @CGP if there is nothing missing, could you validate my answer ? thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use a CA certificate. Otherwise, each mobile client will have to manually set your certificate as trusted.

You can potentially embed the certificate as trusted in the mobile app itself (assuming you distribute the app), however it will be a problem when the time comes to renew the certificate, or rekey/replace the certificate for whatever issue.

Using a globally trusted certificate is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, Simone!